# How to get the pid of the last executed command in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, process, background-process

I want to have a shell script like this:

```
my-app &
echo $my-app-pid
```

But I do not know how the get the pid of the just executed command.

I know I can just use the `jobs -p my-app` command to grep the pid. But if I want to execute the shell multiple times, this method will not work. Because the *jobspec* is ambiguous.

Comment: did you try `echo $!`? right after the command, you ran?

Answer (score 448, accepted):

The PID of the last executed command is in the [`$!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0021-1) shell variable:

```
my-app &
echo $!
```

Comment: It is printing pid as for eg. [1] 893 . I want only number.

Comment: It should be noted that this stands for programs started *in the background*. If no background processes have been started the parameter is not set.

Comment: Another worthy solution is suggested in (a comment to an answer to) [How to get pid of just started process](http://serverfault.com/a/205563/68972): oh, and the "oneliner": `/bin/sh -c 'echo $$>/tmp/my.pid && exec program args' &` –  sysfault Nov 24 '10 at 14:28

Comment: @user3153014 String s like "[2] 2625" are printed by shell after starting background task. This is not related to output of `echo $!`

Comment: I usually use such code in a script when I need to wait until the process ends. `my-app & myVar=$! ; fg`. `fg` brings the process to foreground again. I can then print `echo $myVar` later and I'm pretty sure that the my-app has already finished.

Comment: If you are using that inside `su {user} -c {command}` as `command`, be sure to escape the `$!` (use `\$!`). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147916/getting-the-process-id-out-of-command-launched-with-su-c

Comment: @VrataBlazek `fg: no job control`

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Why is it necessary to pipe the PID to a file?  If I try to wrap the shell call with $() it hangs at that point... why can't I get it into a shell variable directly? When I try to pipe it to a file I have another problem - now the PID of my command isn't the same as reported, whereas if I don't pipe it's the same!

Comment: @Michael Hiw do you want to get it into a shell variable directly? If you suggest a method, I could try to say whether it would work or not. As for `$()` wrapping, I can't try to explain the behavior without seeing the exact code.

Answer (score 88):

Get `PID`:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app &
echo $!
```

Save `PID` in variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app &
export APP_PID=$!
```

Save all instances `PID` in text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app &
echo $! >>/tmp/my-app.pid
```

Save output, errors and `PID` in separated files:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-app >/tmp/my-app.log 2>/tmp/my-app.error.log &
echo $! >>/tmp/my-app.pid

echo "my-app PID's: $(cat /tmp/my-app.pid)"
```

Comment: The question didn't ask about redirection, then your answer is the mostly the same as the accepted one except that if an instance of `my-app` finishes, and perhaps even worse its PID gets reused later, you'll have bad information in your file.  I don't think this answer adds much of value to the existing accepted answer really

Comment: @EricRenouf post updated!

Comment: another derivative that might be useful. This gets the PID and at the same time treats it as a (mostly) foreground process: `sleep 4 | grep INVALID & export MY_PID=$!; fg; echo $MY_PID returned with $?`
`

Comment: isnt APP=`main &` a way to grab PID?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
pidof my_app >> /tmp/my_app.pid
```

Comment: external command, and slow, if system can give PID directly why searching through all processes to find just that? and also, can't be certain you'll get correct value

Answer (score -5):

Try something like this:

```
 ps ef | grep "[m]y-app" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Placing the first letter of your process between `[` `]` makes sure you do not get the `grep` process in your list. If needed you can also add a grep on your username.

Comment: That's very fragile at best and doesn't work if `my-app` is executed more than once - **davidshen84** specifically worries about that cas.

Comment: If you even go this route, you should use ```pgrep``` instead.