# Get PID of a function executed in the background

Tags: bash, process, background-process

```
#!/bin/bash

function abc() # wait for some event to happen, can be terminated by other process
{
    sleep 3333 
}

echo "PID: $$"
abc &
echo "PID: $$"
```

I need to retrieve the `pid` of this function, but the echo prints the same string.

If I'm not going to put `abc()` out of this script, is it possible to get it's `pid` and terminate that function?

Comment: This question is very similar to [How to get the pid of the last executed command in shell script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30370/4319). The only essential difference is that this questions is asking about a **function**. But, as it turns out, it doesn't make the answer different (the function is executed in a backgrounded subshell).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have two options, I think:

`$BASHPID` or `$!`

```
echo "version: $BASH_VERSION"
function abc() # wait for some event to happen, can be terminated by other process
{
          echo "inside a subshell $BASHPID" # This gives you the PID of the current instance of Bash.
          sleep 3333
}

echo "PID: $$" # (i)
abc &
echo "PID: $$" # (ii)
echo "another way $!" # This gives you the PID of the last job run in background
echo "same than (i) and (ii) $BASHPID" # This should print the same result than (i) and (ii)

sh-4.2$ ps ax|grep foo
25094 pts/13   S      0:02 vim foo.sh
25443 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep foo

sh-4.2$ ./foo.sh
version: 4.2.39(2)-release
PID: 25448
PID: 25448
another way 25449
same than (i) and (ii) 25448
inside a subshell 25449

sh-4.2$ ps ax|grep foo
25094 pts/13   S      0:02 vim foo.sh
25449 pts/13   S      0:00 /bin/bash ./foo.sh
25452 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep foo
```

Cheers,

Source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: As my test, normally $! is enough to get the single background process PID, sometimes if i run multiple background child processes (run as function following by &), it will only able to get accurate child PID with $BASHPID, especially when you want to retrieve child process itself PID inside your child process which running in background, e.g function my_func() {  echo $BASHPID ....  } will print accurate PID for my_func, if we run as my_func arg1 arg2 ... &

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the $!

```
function abc() # wait for some event to happen, can be terminated by other process
{
    sleep 3333 
}

echo "PID: $$"
abc &
echo "PID: $!"
```

Comment: “!$”? Is that `$!` with a typo?

Comment: @manatwork yes. Fixed now.