# PID of background function "$!" gives wrong value

Tags: bash, process, kill, background-process, process-groups

I am trying to capture the PID of a function executed in the background, but I seem to get the wrong number.

See the following script:

```bsh
$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

set -x

child() {
    echo "Child thinks is $$"
    sleep 5m 
}

child &
child_pid="$!"
echo "Parent thinks pid $child_pid"

sleep 3
kill -- -"$child_pid" # but it is wrong, get "No such process"

kill -- -"$$"
wait
```

I would expect the parent to terminate the child process of the function, but I get:

```bsh
$ ./test1.sh 
+ child_pid=44551
+ echo 'Parent thinks pid 44551'
Parent thinks pid 44551
+ sleep 3
+ child
+ echo 'Child thinks is 44550'
Child thinks is 44550
+ sleep 5m
+ kill -- -44551
./test1.sh: line 15: kill: (-44551) - No such process
+ kill -- -44550
Terminated
```

I have read this question [Get PID of a function executed in the background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/get-pid-of-a-function-executed-in-the-background), but the answers seem to contradict what I am observing.

So how can I fix the above code, to get the correct PID of the function from the parent?

---

After some testing it seems that the command without the minus works

```bsh
kill -- "$child_pid"
```

But this isn't sufficient for my need, because I want to terminate any subprocesses of `child` too when I kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$!` gives the correct value.
`$$` does not. Use `$BASHPID` instead

See `man bash`:

> **BASHPID**
>
> Expands to the process ID of the current bash process. This differs from $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require bash to be re-initialized. Assignments to BASHPID have no effect.

Not sure, why your `kill -- -PID` is not working, cannot reproduce. You could use `pkill -P PID` instead.

Comment: `kill` with a negative PID argument will kill a process group with that group ID. There is no process group with ID 44551 (the group is probably 44550).

Comment: @Kusalananda: In light of your comment, `pkill -P PID` isn't equivalent to `kill -- -PID`, since it wouldn't terminate the children of the children. So would the only solution  be to somehow create a new process group for the `child` function?

Comment: @user000001 This isn't a topic I'm really good at. You may want to ask a separate question about it. You current question is about the error you get and how to get the correct PID in the function, not _really_ about how to signal all processes started from the function.