# Getting the process-id out of command launched with "su -c"

Tags: bash, shell, su

I am running a java program inside a shell and writing the process-id to a text file.
So when I do this:

```
nohup java app.Main > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > /var/run/app.pid
```

It works. But I really want to run it as another user

```
su - appuser -c "nohup java app.Main > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
echo $! > /var/run/app.pid
```

This doesn't work. Is there any way of getting the process-id of the command launched with the -c option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
su - appuser -c 'nohup java app.Main > /dev/null 2>&1 &
                 echo "$!"' > /var/run/app.pid
```

(that assumes the login shell of `appuser` is Bourne-like).

`su -` resets the environment, so if you want to have variables expanded in the command line, it has to be done by *your* shell (not the login shell of the remote user) like:

```
su - appuser -c "nohup '$JAVA_BIN' '$JAVA_CLASS' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'
                 echo "$!"' > /var/run/app.pid
```

(that assumes those variables don't contain single quote characters).

You want the redirection to be performed by your shell (running as `root`), not `appuser`'s shell (which probably doesn't have write permission to `/var/run`).