# Run an app with a window manager behind in a separate X server

Tags: shell-script, x11, window-manager, session, exit

I want to launch an app in a separate X server. It needs a window manager behind it, though.

I created a script

```
#!/bin/sh
x-window-manager &
my-gui-app
```

and launched it with

```
xinit myscript.sh -- :1
```

The problem is: even after closing the app, the window manager keeps running. I want it to quit after `my-gui-app` exits.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: You may want to use Xephyr

Comment: @sebelk could you please elaborate?

Comment: Store the PID using ``$!``. See [How to get the pid of the last executed command in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30371)

Answer (score 5):

Try to add a last line 
`kill %1`
In interactive shells at least you can kill the pid of the background job this way. Otherwise look if the process can write a pid file or use `killall`, if you're sure, there's only one process of this wm

Answer (score 1):

`kill -TERM -$$` (kill current process group) should also do it in a race condition-safe manner.

This or `kill %` should be preferred to killing by `pid` or by `name`.

Comment: Killing the process group might kill parents of the script, depending on how it was started. If you want to use process groups here, use `setsid` or otherwise ensure that the shell runs in its own process group.